# Как усреднить числа в колонке

Tags: python, numpy

Есть такой массив:

```
[[0.00717204 0.99282524 0.00717016 0.9928248 ]
 [0.00717212 0.99282545 0.00717548 0.99282832]
 [0.00717443 0.9928242  0.00717098 0.9928261 ]
 [0.5        0.5        0.5        0.5       ]]
```

Как можно усреднить числа в столбиках, чтобы получился массив такого вида:

```
[[усредненное число, ... ,усредненное число]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [np.mean](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html):

```
import numpy as np

In [5]: res = np.mean(arr, axis=0)

In [6]: res
Out[6]: array([0.13037965, 0.86961872, 0.13037915, 0.8696198 ])
```

или методом [ndarray.mean()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.mean.html):

```
In [7]: res = arr.mean(axis=0)

In [8]: res
Out[8]: array([0.13037965, 0.86961872, 0.13037915, 0.8696198 ])
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array ([[0.00717204, 0.99282524, 0.00717016, 0.9928248 ],
 [0.00717212, 0.99282545, 0.00717548, 0.99282832],
 [0.00717443, 0.9928242,  0.00717098, 0.9928261 ],
 [0.5,        0.5,        0.5,        0.5,       ]])

result = []

for i in range(len(arr[0])):
    result.append(np.mean(arr[:, i], axis=0))
```

Список `result` будет содержать нужные Вам значения.

Что здесь происходит:

`arr[:, i]` получает i-ый столбец (нумерация начинается с нуля) двумерного массива `numpy` в виде списка.

`np.mean(arr, axis=0)` вычисляет среднее значение массива `arr` по его нулевой "оси", т.е. по первому измерению.

Comment: @MaxU Спасибо, поправил.